# Link or use a c++ library inside crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

I was wonder if it was possible to use a library like [this](http://libevent.org/) in our crystal program to help schedule events or can we create a crystal shard that can interface with libevent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[bindgen](https://github.com/Papierkorb/bindgen) is a binding and wrapper generator for C/C++ libraries for Crystal

Comment: This is correct but @coderhs is specifically asking about binding and using libevent manually, which is unlikely to be the right way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

Libevent is already used by the crystal standard library to provided evented IO and the `sleep` function. You shouldn't need to bind libevent manually, just use normal IO, `sleep` and fibers. You can learn about how crystal handles concurrency [here](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/guides/concurrency.html).